# Using `foreign import prim` with a C function using STG calling convention

Tags: c, haskell, segmentation-fault, ghc, ffi

I have a simple C routine that takes four words and returns four words, and for which gcc can optimize and emit some primops that GHC doesn't support. I'm trying to benchmark various  ways of calling this procedure, and am having trouble trying to adapt the technique [described here](http://breaks.for.alienz.org/blog/2012/02/09/parsing-market-data-feeds-with-ragel/) to use `foreign import prim`.

The following is meant to just add 1 to each input word, but segfaults.

Main.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GHCForeignImportPrim #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnliftedFFITypes #-}
import Foreign.C
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Int
import GHC.Word

foreign import prim "sipRound"
  sipRound_c# :: Word# -> Word# -> Word# -> Word# -> (# Word#, Word#, Word#, Word# #)

sipRound_c ::  Word64 -> Word64 -> Word64 -> Word64 -> (Word64, Word64, Word64, Word64)
sipRound_c (W64# v0) (W64# v1) (W64# v2) (W64# v3) = case sipRound_c# v0 v1 v2 v3 of
  (# v0', v1', v2', v3' #) -> (W64# v0', W64# v1', W64# v2', W64# v3')

main = do
  print $ sipRound_c 1 2 3 4
```

sip.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



// define a function pointer type that matches the STG calling convention
typedef void (*HsCall)(int64_t*, int64_t*, int64_t*, int64_t, int64_t, int64_t, int64_t,
                       int64_t, int64_t, int64_t*, float, float, float, float, double, double);

extern void
sipRound(
    int64_t* restrict baseReg,
    int64_t* restrict sp,
    int64_t* restrict hp,

    uint64_t v0, // R1
    uint64_t v1, // R2
    uint64_t v2, // R3
    uint64_t v3, // R4
    int64_t r5,
    int64_t r6,

    int64_t* restrict spLim,
    float f1,
    float f2,
    float f3,
    float f4,
    double d1,
    double d2)
{

    v0 += 1;
    v1 += 1;
    v2 += 1;
    v3 += 1;

    // create undefined variables, clang will emit these as a llvm undef literal
    const int64_t iUndef;
    const float fUndef;
    const double dUndef;

    const HsCall fun = (HsCall)sp[0];
    return fun(
            baseReg,
            sp,
            hp,

            v0,
            v1,
            v2,
            v3,
            iUndef,
            iUndef,

            spLim,
            fUndef,
            fUndef,
            fUndef,
            fUndef,
            dUndef,
            dUndef);
}
```

I don't really know what I'm doing. Is there a way to adapt the technique from that blog post? And is this a bad idea?

Comment: This is very, very low level. Do you really need this level of performance? AFAICS, the blog post generates LLVM using clang, then patches the output by changing the C call convention to LLVM cc10 (the GHC one), and then compiler the result with llc. Scary. This is way beyond by comfort zone (i.e., I have very little knowledge of what's going on at this level), but using the cc10 calling convention seems to be crucial!

Comment: @chi I'm in the process of also benchmarking returning a struct of 4 words from a normal foreign ccall, but I'm expecting the overhead to be too great to be worth it (but might be surprised); I'm going through all this to try to get rotate instructions generated when not using the LLVM backend, for a library I'm working on. But this is also out of curiousity

Comment: Right, this won't work. As the blog post says: "This is still a ccall function but we’ll fix that later. There is currently no way to define this as cc10 (LLVM’s internal name for GHC’s calling convention) in clang." The C calling convention is different from GHC's. For example C thinks the first argument `baseReg` should be in `rdi` (assuming x86_64) but GHC is passing `baseReg` in `r13`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to hand-write assembly you can do it like this (for x86_64). Put this in a file with a `.s` extension and provide it as an argument on the ghc command line.

```
.global sipRound
sipRound:
    inc %rbx
    inc %r14
    inc %rsi
    inc %rdi
    jmp *(%rbp)
```

The mapping between STG registers and machine registers is defined in https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/includes/stg/MachRegs.h#L159.

Note that there will still be a function call involved, so it won't be as efficient as the code you are getting from LLVM.

Comment: I understand this much better now, thanks! Two quick followups: to expose this to ghc do we need to use inline asm in a c file, like `void sipRound() { asm ( ... )}` or is there a better way to do it (and is that why you say "there will be a function call involved"?)? And can I consider this a stable API? It looks as though that mapping hasn't changed much, and has to stay stable to coordinate with llvm etc.

Comment: You can't use `void sipRound() { asm ( ... )}` since that will add a C function prologue. Just provide the assembler input like any other input. The function call I am talking about is the call you write to `sipRound_c#`. The point is that GHC can't "inline" `sipRound`, since it is implemented in assembly. (By contrast when you call `+#`, GHC doesn't generate a call to top-level function; it emits an add instruction.)

Comment: The ABI doesn't change much but it's not guaranteed to be stable; there's no ABI compatibility between different versions of GHC and each version of GHC only works with one version of LLVM, so it wouldn't be hard to get the modified calling convention into the next version of LLVM.

Comment: Also, I'm curious whether you find this is actually faster for you than a regular FFI call.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to update here after measuring both ways

Comment: And `void sipRound() { asm ( ... )}` did seem to work for me for whatever reason, but thanks for the edit!

Comment: Yeah it's possible for the C compiler to realize that a prologue is unnecessary and not insert one, but it's not guaranteed to work in general.

Comment: I'm measuring 6 ns per iteration for the haskell function wrapping the assembly translation of a [SIPROUND](https://github.com/veorq/SipHash/blob/93ca99dcfa6a32b1b617e9a5c3c044685254ce8e/siphash.c#L44) using this approach, so I am going to be lazy for now and not benchmark allocating a struct, peeking in haskell-land, etc. This is a much nicer interface to work with anyway!

Comment: Just posted a followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41528208/why-is-there-no-foreign-import-prim-unsafe