# Why is there no 'foreign import prim unsafe'?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

This is a followup to my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213378/using-foreign-import-prim-with-a-c-function-using-stg-calling-convention). I've been able to get something working per [Reid Barton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41214165/176841), but I notice in the core I see `__pkg_ccall_GC`:

```
              case {__pkg_ccall_GC hashabler-2.0.0 sipRound_s_x2 Word#
                                          -> Word#
                                          -> Word#
                                          -> Word#
                                          -> (# Word#, Word#, Word#, Word# #)}
                     ww1 ww2 ww3 (xor# ww4 b1)
```

Which is I think what you'd expect for a "safe" ffi call. Yet adding "unsafe" to the foreign import string is not allowed (though the error messages doesn't say why):

```
src/Data/Hashabler/SipHash.hs:60:1: error:
    • The safe/unsafe annotation should not be used with `foreign import prim'.
    • When checking declaration:
        foreign import prim unsafe "static sipRound_s_x4" sipRound_s_x4#
          :: Word#
             -> Word# -> Word# -> Word# -> (# Word#, Word#, Word#, Word# #)
```

My foreign procedure is just a little but of bit-twiddling, so I don't think I want whatever the `_GC` is giving me. Some relevant bits of GHC source I've looked at, FWIW and background:

compiler/prelude/ForeignCall.hs: only "Risky" omits the "_GC"

```
data Safety
  = PlaySafe            -- Might invoke Haskell GC, or do a call back, or
                        -- switch threads, etc.  So make sure things are
                        -- tidy before the call. Additionally, in the threaded
                        -- RTS we arrange for the external call to be executed
                        -- by a separate OS thread, i.e., _concurrently_ to the
                        -- execution of other Haskell threads.

  | PlayInterruptible   -- Like PlaySafe, but additionally
                        -- the worker thread running this foreign call may
                        -- be unceremoniously killed, so it must be scheduled
                        -- on an unbound thread.

  | PlayRisky           -- None of the above can happen; the call will return
                        -- without interacting with the runtime system at all
  deriving ( Eq, Show, Data )
        -- Show used just for Show Lex.Token, I think
```

I also see some `foreign import prim unsafe` and `... safe` in the GHC tree, though I suppose it's dead code. e.g. `testsuite/tests/printer/Ppr046.hs`.

So my questions are:

1. What is the difference between code generated from a `__pkg_ccall_GC` vs a `__pkg_ccall` in this case (where I'm doing `foreign import prim` not `ccall`)? Is it the same as described [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Unsafe_calls)?
2. Why doesn't a `foreign import prim unsafe` seem to be supported?
3. Assuming I understand (1): Is there anyway I can work around this, getting both efficient return of multiple values and avoiding whatever bookkeeping is happening in (1)?

---

**EDIT**: Looking at the assembly from `-ddump-asm` makes it clear nothing much is happening (shouldn't have been scared to look at the assembly), support Reid Barton's comment below:

```
movq %rdi,%rax
movq %r8,%rdi 
xorq %r9,%rdi
movq %rsi,%rcx
movq %rax,%rsi
movq %r14,%rax
movq %rcx,%r14
movq %rbx,%rcx
movq %rax,%rbx
movq %r9,-8(%rbp)
movq %rcx,(%rbp)
addq $-16,%rbp
jmp sipRound_s_x2
```

The `xorq` towards the top corresponds to a haskell `xor`. All those `movq` do seem to be a bummer though...

Comment: If you look at the generated Cmm there's none of the `suspendThread`/`resumeThread` stuff you'd see around a safe call. I don't know why it shows `__pkg_ccall_GC` in Core, maybe just a display bug.

Comment: @ReidBarton Thanks once again :) Do you think I should file a little bug?

Comment: Aren't those `movq` to get the arguments into the right registers before the tail call?  They don't look redundant to me.

Comment: Probably worth filing a bug yes--it looks like `prim` imports are marked `PlaySafe` by the parser, which is presumably mostly ignored, and definitely ignored during code generation. But wherever it's not ignored there could be a bug.

Comment: @augustss yeah they are, but wouldn't we want the register allocation algorithm to do away with a lot of that? e.g. I could "optimize" this by simply changing which registers I'm using for what in `sipRound_s_x2`; those moves are shuffling around `rsi`, `r14` and `rdi`. But I'm speaking out of ignorance, as I have very little experience with this stuff. It's just that at a high level the algorithm I'm working with can be implemented quite naturally without these moves

Comment: But then I suppose `sipRound_s_x2` is a black box to GHC, so perhaps that's the issue? Or perhaps the register allocation tries its best to "work backward" from that call, but can't always get things to line up?

Comment: You'd have to do global register allocation to avoid argument shuffling.  I don't think ghc does that. Have you tried the llvm code generator?

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling to compare them though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Reid Barton points out the `__pkg_ccall_GC` doesn't indicate anything. The code generated doesn't do the bookkeeping you would see in a `safe` FFI call.